# how to split dataframe in R

Tags: r

Suppose there is x with all numeric values

```
 set.seed(0) 
 system.time( x <- replicate(10000 ,rexp(rpois(1,1.2), rate=0.1)) )
```

when I get this in excel using

```
rinterface.GetArray "x", Range("a1")
```

it goes in excel column A.How can I split the x and get values in excel in different columns, For example it should be stored like

```
      Col A Col B Col C Col D
  1   11     2       3     40
  2   1      2       3
  3   0
  4   4
```

Comment: I meant about the `'`

Comment: `df<-(c(11,2,3,40),c(1,2,3),numeric(0),4)` is not anything in `R`

Comment: Is this actually a question about splitting a single cell in Excel?

Comment: @akrun it's not a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I understood your question.

`df` is not a data frame but a vector. You have to use a list, since your vectors are of unequal size.
You can use the following code to get a matrix as you wish inside R and also write to a .csv file which can be open in Excel (`res.transposed` has the data frame that you want):

```
set.seed(0) 
system.time( x <- replicate(10000 ,rexp(rpois(1,1.2), rate=0.1)) )
max.size <- max(lengths(x))

res <- mapply(function(l, s){
    if(is.numeric(l) && length(l) == 0){
        c(0, rep(NA, max.size - 1))
    }else{
        c(l, rep(NA, max.size - length(l)))
}
}, x, max.size)
res.transposed <- as.data.frame(res)

write.csv(res.transposed, 
      file = "~/Desktop/filled_matrix.csv",
      quote = FALSE, 
      na = "")
```

Comment: @HaagenDaz You can substitute `NA` values by "0" inside `mapply` to have an exact matrix like the one you want within R. Because of coding style and meaning, I prefer `NA` since you don't have zeros in your vectors but missing values.

Comment: x is generated using 
'set.seed(0)

system.time(

x <- replicate(10000 ,rexp(rpois(1,1.2), rate=0.1))

  
) ' so x contains 10000 vectors.

Comment: Code still works, as you don't have four vectors as in your example, you just have to get rid of `names(res.transposed) <- c("Col A", "Col B", "Col C", "Col D")` or name your columns as you wish.

Comment: i get an error with the above code "Error: cannot allocate vector of size 391 Kb"

Comment: Can you describe your session information? `sessionInfo()`

Comment: R version 3.1.3 (2015-03-09)
Platform: i386-w64-mingw32/i386 (32-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252 
[2] LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] parallel  stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods  
[8] base     

other attached packages:
[1] evir_1.7-3 evd_2.3-2

Comment: can is use `rinterface.GetDataframe "res.transposed", Sheet2.Range("a1")` to get df in excel?

Answer (score 0):

You have two options, the first is make a data.frame where the blanks are `NA`

```
my.df <- data.frame("A"=c(11,1,0,4),"B"=c(2,2,NA,NA),"C"=c(3,3,NA,NA),"D"=c(40,NA,NA,NA))
```

The second is to use a list, which is better at storing unequal vectors.

```
my.list <- list("A"=c(11,1,0,4),"B"=c(2,2),"C"=c(3,3),"D"=40)
```